# Android Kotlin Flow data filter optimization

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel, clean-architecture, kotlin-flow

I've been working on how to filter my data based on a certain condition.
I worked around the issue by creating a viewModel with a assisted injection for my tag. But I think if I need to do more filtering, this solution is going to be inefficient.
Here's the sample code of what I did

```
sealed interface TasksState {
    data class Success(val tasks: Map<TimeType, RelatedTasksMetaDataResult>): TasksState
    object Loading: TasksState
    object Error: TasksState
}

class TasksViewModel @AssistedInject constructor(
    getTasksFlowUseCase: GetTasksFlowUseCase,
    relatedTasksUseCase: RelatedTasksUseCase,
    @Assisted
    private val selectedTag: Tag
): ViewModel() {

    private val _state = MutableStateFlow<TasksState>(TasksState.Loading)

    val state: StateFlow<TasksState> = _state.asStateFlow()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            tasksUiStream(
                getTasksFlowUseCase,
                relatedTasksUseCase,
                Filter.TagFilter(selectedTag, Grouping.DateGrouping)
            ).collect { _state.value = it }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get all tasks as stream and convert them to UI state
     */
    private fun tasksUiStream(
        getTasksFlowUseCase: GetTasksFlowUseCase,
        relatedTasksUseCase: RelatedTasksUseCase,
        filter: Filter,
        completed: Boolean = false
    ): Flow<TasksState> {
        return getTasksFlowUseCase(
            TasksRetrievalParameters(filter, completed)
        )
            .map { tasksResult ->
                when(tasksResult) {
                    is Success -> {
                        val groupedTasks = tasksResult.data
                        val tasks = mutableMapOf<TimeType, RelatedTasksMetaDataResult>()
                        groupedTasks?.forEach{  groupedTask ->
                            /* Make sure the keys of the grouped tasks are instance of TimeType  */
                            val dueDate = groupedTask.key as? TimeType
                            dueDate?.let {
                                tasks[dueDate] = relatedTasksUseCase(groupedTask.value)
                            }
                        }
                        TasksState.Success(tasks.toSortedMap())
                    }
                    is Loading -> {
                        TasksState.Loading
                    }
                    is Error -> {
                        TasksState.Error
                    }
                }
            }
    }

    @AssistedFactory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(selectedTag: Tag): TasksViewModel
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    companion object {
        fun provideFactory(
            assistedFactory: Factory,
            selectedTag: Tag
        ): ViewModelProvider.Factory = object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
            override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
                return assistedFactory.create(selectedTag) as T
            }
        }
    }

}
```

So what I tried to do instead now, is to use a mutable state flow and filter once the value change. Here's the sample code:

```
data class UiState(
    val filterQuery: FilterQuery = FilterQuery(),
    val projectsState: ProjectsState = ProjectsState.Loading
)

sealed interface ProjectsState {
    object Loading: ProjectsState
    data class Success(val projects: List<ProjectResult>): ProjectsState
    object Error: ProjectsState
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
@HiltViewModel
class ProjectsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    getAllProjectsFlowUseCase: GetAllProjectsFlowUseCase,
    getProjectsFlowUseCase: GetProjectsFlowUseCase,
    private val upsertProjectUseCase: UpsertProjectUseCase
): ViewModel() {

    private val _filterQuery = MutableStateFlow(FilterQuery())

    val state: StateFlow<UiState> = _filterQuery
        .flatMapLatest {
            getProjectsFlowUseCase(it)
                .mapLatest { result ->
                    UiState(
                        filterQuery = it,
                        projectsState =
                            when(result) {
                                is Result.Success -> ProjectsState.Success(result.data ?: emptyList())
                                is Result.Loading -> ProjectsState.Loading
                                is Result.Error -> ProjectsState.Error
                            }
                    )
                }
        }
        .stateIn(
            viewModelScope,
            SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
            UiState()
        )

}
```

Unfortunately with this approach, once I move to the screen, the screen keeps loading with the initial state without emitting the data(But also sometimes the date are emitted directly). In order for the value to be emitted if that occurs, I have to change the filter query on the screen and change it again back to the initial state.

Is there any better approach to filter data based on certain value with kotlin Flow ?